# XWPFDocument returning 1 number of pages for docx file

Tags: java, docx

I am using XWPFDocument library to find number of pages in docx file. Below is my code snippet :

```
XWPFDocument docx = null;
            try {
                docx = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage(filePath));
                totalPages = docx.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error while loading word document at file location {}", filePath);
                totalPages = 0;
            }
```

For some .docx it is working fine but for some files it is returning 1 inspite of having more than 30 pages.

Comment: Your code seems fine..try adding a breakpoint in the catch block and dubug for those documents which shows 1 page

Comment: I have checked that and there is no exception seen. totalPages is coming as 1 from                 totalPages = docx.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
 line.

Comment: Did you try with docx.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getPages(); ?

Comment: The file doesn't contain information about the "actual" number of pages "after rendering". You would first need to open the document with Word and read the property afterwards because Word will only update it after rendering (applying the styles to the texts, etc.).